Physics of imported DAZ Studio hair
I've imported a character from Daz Studio along with some mesh hair. The hair is made of mesh strips attached to a skull cap. I want to make the hair look like it's been affected by gravity; e.g. spreading out over a hard surface or over the shoulders of the character. I've tried sculpting the hair (e.g. smoothing, grabbing, etc.), but without success. Is there some way of using Blender physics to achieve the effect I want? Links to tutorials would be gratefully received.

Cloth physics for the hair cards should work. Use the Pin Group setting to control which hair parts are loose and which are pinned. Here is an example for UE5, but it should work the same way in Blender: https://www.artstation.com/artwork/LRlBAl
